# Java and MySQL, SELECT works; INSERT does not

Tags: java, mysql, select, insert

I'm doing a Java WebService which perfors some SQL querys.

The SELECT FROM a table method works properly.
But the INSERT INTO statement does not; it doen't update the database's table actually. I'm guessing why.

The SELECT FROM method:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "retrievePlayer")
public String retrievePlayer(@WebParam(name = "user") String user, @WebParam(name = "password") String password)
    {

    String customerInfo = "";

    try
      {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "root");

      PreparedStatement statement
        =  con.prepareStatement("select user, password, level from mytable where user=\"" + user + "\";");
       ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

       while(result.next())
          {
          customerInfo = customerInfo
                     + result.getString("user")
                     + "&" + result.getString("password")
                     + "&"+result.getString("level");
          }
       }
       catch(Exception exc){ System.out.println(exc.getMessage()); }        

       return customerInfo;
       }
```

The INSERT method, which does not work:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "createPlayer")
public void createPlayer(@WebParam(name = "user") String user, @WebParam(name = "password") String password)
    {
    try
      {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "root");

      PreparedStatement statement
            =  con.prepareStatement("insert into mytable ('user', 'password', 'level') values ('" + user + "','" + password + "','0,1');");
      statement.executeQuery();*/

      }
    catch(Exception exc){ System.out.println(exc.getMessage()); }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change this:
values ('" + user + "','" + password + "','0,1')
to this:
values ('" + user + "','" + password + "','0.1')

Comment: should you call `executeUpdate()` ?

Comment: **Side note**: Your use of `PreparedStatement` is wrong. You must not include parameters in the query itself, put question marks where they should be placed and insert them with the `PreparedStatement#setXXX` methods

Comment: What is the error message ???; also you should use parametrized queries

Comment: Everybody who answered to use executeUpdate() were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting, swap

```
statement.executeQuery
```

with

```
statement.executeUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

use

**statement.executeUpdate();**

for insert

use

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (user, password, level)" +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";


PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "user");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "password");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "0,1");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this code:

```
public void addUser(User user)
    {
        try
        {   
Query=insert into mytable (user, password, level) values (?,?,?)");
PreparedStatement Statement = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
Statement.setString(1, user.getuser());
Statement.setString(2, user.getpassword());
Statement.setString(3, user.getlevel());
Statement.executeUpdate();              
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change your query to `statement.executeupdate`